# How can we generate new sampling points by bilinear interpolation?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a picture in grayscle and I need to generate new sampling points (circled in red in the picture)  by bilinear interpolation. Is there a formula or a function to compute the values of these points in python?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a minimal example to get started? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually, I am searching for an idea to get sarted

Answer (score 1):

According to the diagram, it doesn't look like bi-linear interpolation, it looks like an average between two angles.

I am not sure if my solution is what you are looking for, but I assume it gives you a lead...

I tried solving it by finding the circle automatically using `cv2.HoughCircles`, and mark `x`, `y` positions using trigonometry.

The solution uses the following stages:

- Convert image to gray and to binary.
- Find circles using `cv2.HoughCircles`.
- Iterate circles, and find the circle with center closest to the center of the image.
- Compute angles in steps of 45 degrees `[0, 45, 90, 135...]`, name them `alpha`.
  Compute angles between the above angles `[22.5, 67.5, 112.5...]`, name them `beta`.
  We don't really need `alpha` for computing `beta`.
  It is just for demonstrating the kind of interpolation you suppose to do.
- Compute `x`, `y` of each point using trigonometry.
  Mark "alpha" points with cyan circles.
  Mark "beta" points with yellow circles.
  You may store `x`, `y` of "beta" points - those are the points you are looking for.

---

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input imgae
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Convert to Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to binary image, and invert polarity
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

rows, cols = thresh.shape

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=rows//8, param1=50, param2=60, minRadius=rows//8, maxRadius=rows//2)

# Find the circle with center closest to the center of the image
min_dist_from_center = 1e9
min_c = []
for c in circles[0,:]:
    # Euclidean distance from the center of circle to center of image
    dist_from_center = np.linalg.norm([c[0] - cols/2, c[1] - rows/2])
    if dist_from_center < min_dist_from_center:
        min_dist_from_center = dist_from_center
        min_c = c

c = min_c

# Draw circle for testing
cv2.circle(img, (c[0], c[1]), c[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Array of angles in 45 degrees difference
alpha_arr = np.arange(0, 360+45, 45)  # [  0,  45,  90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360]
betta_arr = (alpha_arr[1:] + alpha_arr[0:-1])/2  # [ 22.5,  67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5] Points between alpha

# Compute x, y coordinates by angle and radius
r = c[2]
for alpha, beta in zip(alpha_arr[:-1], betta_arr):
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(alpha)) + c[0] # x = r*cos(alpha) + center_x
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(alpha)) + c[1] # y = r*sin(alpha) + center_y

    # Draw small cyan circle to mark alpha points
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 12, (255, 255, 0), 3)

    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(beta)) + c[0] # x = r*cos(alpha) + center_x
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(beta)) + c[1] # y = r*sin(alpha) + center_y

    # Draw small yellow circle to mark beta points
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 10, (0, 255, 255), 3)


# Show images for testing
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]